# Making a nested function run in parallel using multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am attempting to model space and hot water heat demand for many dwellings (order of thousands) at hourly resolution for several years.

I have the following code that currently takes roughly 1 minute per year but I need to do this over many years and locations. Weatherdata is a dataframe of monitored hourly metdata. Buildings is a tuple of class objects, each one a dwelling, containing data and functions such as waterdemand and heatdemand.

```
import pandas as pd

for timestamp, data in weatherdata.iterrows():
    
    for dwelling in range(len(Buildings)):

        hotwater[dwelling] = Buildings[dwelling].waterdemand(timestamp)
        heating[dwelling]  = Buildings[dwelling].heatdemand(timestamp, data.ambtemp, data.solar, data.windspeed)

    resultdict.append({ 'timestamp'    : timestamp,
                        'Heating_kWh'  : sum(heating),
                        'HotWater_kWh' : sum(hotwater) })    
    
results = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(resultdict)
```

To speed things up, the inner loop is able to run in parallel. I have explored using Numba and prange to make this loop run in parallel but am not able to as it cannot run in nopython mode due to using class functions and pandas. The alternative I have found is multiprocessing and the loop be run in parallel processes. I can write the inner loop as a function but am not sure how to run only the this - parallel_function in parallel using multiprocessing.

```
def parallel_funct(timestamp, data):
    for dwelling in range(len(Buildings)):

        hotwater[dwelling] = Buildings[dwelling].waterdemand(timestamp)
        heating[dwelling]  = Buildings[dwelling].heatdemand(timestamp, data.ambtemp, data.solar, data.windspeed)
    return sum(heating), sum(hotwater)

for timestamp, data in weatherdata.iterrows():
    
    heating, hotwater = parallel_function(timestamp, data)

    resultdict.append({ 'timestamp'    : timestamp,
                        'Heating_kWh'  : heating,
                        'HotWater_kWh' : hotwater })    
    
results = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(resultdict)
```

I am trying to make this work with multiprocessing but am unsure how to structure this.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
if __name__ == '__main__':

    for timestamp, data in weatherdata.iterrows():

        heating, hotwater = Process(target=parallel_funct(timestamp, data), args=len(Buildings))
        resultdict.append({ 'timestamp'    : timestamp,
                            'Heating_kWh'  : heating,
                            'HotWater_kWh' : hotwater })
```

I understand that this code cannot work without the other data and functions but any help will be welcome.